# Using as_survey_design and other functions within a function

Tags: r, function, survey

I'm trying to automatize my code and I'd like to create a function compute_deciles which creates two data frames that contain deciles.

```
compute_deciles <- function (varh,varf){
  
  deciles_h <- wealth_data %>%
  as_survey_design(ids = 1, weights=pond_trans) %>% 
   summarise(q=survey_quantile(varh,quantile=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9),vartype=c("ci"),level=0.95, na.rm=TRUE))

  
  deciles_f <- wealth_data %>%
    as_survey_design(ids = 1, weights=pond_trans) %>%
    summarise(q=survey_quantile(varf,quantile=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9),vartype=c("ci"),level=0.95, na.rm=TRUE))
}

compute_deciles(varh=W_h_hyp1, varf=W_f_hyp1)
```

I got the following error message : Erreur : Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
ℹ In argument: `q = survey_quantile(...)`.
Caused by error:
! objet 'W_h_hyp1' introuvable

Could you help me with this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible [tidy evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
data(api)
compute_deciles <- function (varh){
  deciles_h <- apistrat %>%
        as_survey_design(strata = stype, weights = pw) %>% 
        summarise(q=survey_quantile({{varh}}, 
           quantile=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9), vartype=c("ci"), 
           level=0.95, na.rm=TRUE))
  deciles_h
  }
```

giving

```
> compute_deciles(api00)
# A tibble: 1 × 27
  q_q10 q_q20 q_q30 q_q40 q_q50 q_q60 q_q70 q_q80 q_q90 q_q10_low q_q20_low
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1   501   542   588   631   668   703   740   774   836       476       522
# ℹ 16 more variables: q_q30_low <dbl>, q_q40_low <dbl>, q_q50_low <dbl>,
#   q_q60_low <dbl>, q_q70_low <dbl>, q_q80_low <dbl>, q_q90_low <dbl>,
#   q_q10_upp <dbl>, q_q20_upp <dbl>, q_q30_upp <dbl>, q_q40_upp <dbl>,
#   q_q50_upp <dbl>, q_q60_upp <dbl>, q_q70_upp <dbl>, q_q80_upp <dbl>,
#   q_q90_upp <dbl>
```

The evaluation issue was that your code tried to evaluate `varh` and pass the resulting vector, which was introuvable. What you want to do is substitute-and-requote on `varh` to get the same effect as typing `W_h_hyp1` into the call to `survey_quantile`. The `{{ }}` operator does this, and the result is trouvable.

There were other issues with the code. It didn't actually return anything, which I fixed.  It also has the data set hard-coded into the function, which I didn't fix but I substituted a data set that's available in the `survey` package so that the example is reproducible.